# throw exception issue in String array

Tags: java, try-catch, java.util.scanner

Array does not passes first catch. it throws the exception at the first try. if statement appears to be correct at InvalidTimeException.  What could be the problem? Thanks in advance.

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    Scanner kybd = new Scanner (System.in);

    Exception TimeInUseException = new Exception("Time is taken!");
    Exception InvalidTimeException = new Exception("Time is not valid!");

    String [] schedule = new String[5];

    for(int i = 0; i<schedule.length; i++){

        System.out.println("Schedule appointment at either 1,2,3,4,5 or 6 o'clock pm ");
        schedule [i]= kybd.nextLine();

        try{

            if(schedule[i]==schedule[i+1])
                throw TimeInUseException;

        }//end of try

        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.print("Program Crashed!");
            break;
        }//end of catch



        try{

            if(schedule[i]!="1" || schedule[i]!="2" || schedule[i]!="3" || schedule[i]!="4" || schedule[i]!="5" || schedule[i]!="6")
                throw InvalidTimeException;
            }//end of try

        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.print("Program Crashed!");
            break;
            }//end of catch

    }//end of forLoop
}//end of main
```

}//end of

Comment: throwing an exception in a try/catch block will catch the exception.  What are you expecting and why are you throwing an exception in a try/catch block?

Comment: if the user puts input outside 1-6 OR if the "time" is already taken

Comment: why is this statement not working?

    System.out.println("Schedule appointment at either 1,2,3,4,5 or 6 o'clock pm ");
   schedule [i]= kybd.nextInt();
   int temp = schedule[i];
   
   try{
    if(i>1)
     if(temp == schedule[i])
       throw TimeInUseException;

after i = 2 if i>1 should pass and temp should equal to [i] so it should throw and exception. why is it not trowing it?

Answer (score 0):

In the line

`if(schedule[i]==schedule[i+1])`

`schedule[i+1]` hasn't been instantiated yet.  So you are comparing against *null*.  The `if` statement won't be true as `schedule[i]` is *not null*.  *not null == null* evaluates to False.

Suggestion:  Create a list and add the used times to a List or better yet a HashSet.  Compare the new entry to the stored values to see if it has already been used.